# How to redirect to another page in angular and Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have problem in redirections in ionic using angular js. here is my code

**`app.js`**

```
angular.module('test', ['ionic', 'test.controllers', ])

.run(function($rootScope, $state, $ionicPlatform, $window) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider

        .state('opener', {
            cache: false,
            url: '/opener',
            templateUrl: 'templates/opener.html',
            controller: 'appController'
        })
        .state('app.main', {
            url: '/main',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
                    controller: 'mainController'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
            controller: 'menuController'
        })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/opener');
})


// controllers.js file 


angular.module('test.controllers', [])

.controller('appController', function($scope, $state, $location) {
        $scope.gotoMain = function() {
            window.localStorage['UserSession'] = 'NOT_LOGIN';
            $location.path("/templates/main");
        }
    })
    .controller('menuController', function($scope) {
        $scope.myClass = "ion-navicon";
        $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
            if ($scope.myClass === "ion-navicon")
                $scope.myClass = "ion-arrow-left-c";
            else
                $scope.myClass = "ion-navicon";
        };
    })

// Main Screen Controller
.controller('mainController', function($scope, $state, $ionicLoading) {

})
```

in the code i have used `$location.path('/path');`

but i have also tried with `$state.go('/path');`
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Add 'ui.router' as a module dependency and then use $state.go(StateName).

Comment: What error you getting.Can you provide a plunker?

Answer (score 2):

Use this    `$state.go('app.main');`

Answer (score 1):

Try using **`$state`** like this,

```
$scope.gotoMain = function() {
    window.localStorage['UserSession'] = 'NOT_LOGIN';
     $state.go('main', {});
}
```

Comment: Error: Could not resolve 'main' from state 'opener' . it's giving this error

Comment: Could you please create a demo ?